Why RTRIM is not working in where condition for the right-side space
I have a temp table in SQL Server with 2 columns. I inserted the data into the table with spaces on the right side of the value as shown below
INSERT INTO #temp ([ACCESS], [USER_ID])
VALUES ('ABC', 'MGD\info    ')

There validation query using RTRIM function is not giving the result of these right-side spaced values.
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM #temp
WHERE RTRIM([USER_ID]) <> [USER_ID]

The expected result of the above query should be 1 row, whereas the query is returning 0 rows.
I tried displaying the same by directly mentioning the space in value as shown in below query and it is showing that 1 row:
SELECT [ACCESS], [USER_ID]  
FROM #temp
WHERE [USER_ID] = 'MGD\info    '

I also tried the similar steps for LTRIM and it is working fine whereas the same is not working with RTRIM

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/04/surprising-behavior-trailing-spaces/

Why so complicated? If I understand correct, you just want to check whether the string ends with a space? If so, you can simply write WHERE user_id LIKE  '% '

As a side note - don't use temp tables - use CTEs instead..

String comparisons ignore trailing spaces. You can instead use DATALENGTH() to compare the true storage lengths (in bytes) before and after the trim.  (Note that LEN() cannot be used because it also ignores trailing spaces.)
select count(*)
from #temp
where DATALENGTH(RTRIM(USER_ID)) <> DATALENGTH(USER_ID)

You can also use LIKE '% ' to check explicitly for a trailing space.
select count(*)
from #temp
where USER_ID LIKE '% '

See this db<>fiddle.
